# Can I replace an object with another object and keep animation?

Tags: animation, objects, bezier-curves

Is it possible to use an element, in this case a ship, in a blender scene and progress through animation and then easily replace that ship with a different one? A replace command?

Comment: 1. replacing the ship during the animation or the same animation with another ship?  2.spin maybe? https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/spin.html

Comment: are there any simulation in the animation " physics , cloth, hair, particles "?

Comment: Please include more information in your questions, it makes it much easier to see what you are asking. Screenshots help as well. Also, never include two questions in one. Please edit one out and post as another.

Comment: Unless the questions are very closely related please don't post them as a single question. You can post several questions in a day.

Comment: I have edited you question down to just one question (the one with two answers already) to avoid this getting closed.  Feel free to post the other question as a separate question though.  We just like to have one question per post to keep things from getting too confusing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way to replace a "replace" button. :)

Create a proxy object that will be animated. Create as many ships as needed. naming them as object and mesh can be useful.
[image]

change the mesh of the proxy object with another ship.

[image]
[image]
[image]

The same animated object can be any ship you like with the same animation.

The resulting object is a linked duplicated, same as <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>. They share the same mesh. If you need an independant duplicate (same as <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>), press the button beside F (normally 2, counting objects sharing the same mesh) to make it a new object independent of the original. Use F button to give the mesh a fake user before changing it if you want it to be saved in the .blend even if no object use it (else it will disapear when you reload your .blend file).

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can copy and paste keyframes in the *dope sheet* using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

[image]

This way you can animate one object, and then copy and paste the keyframes from that to any other objects.

Note (as [Greg Zaal mentioned](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24455/can-i-replace-an-object-with-another-object-and-keep-animation/24458?noredirect=1#comment36050_24458) in the comments) that only objects with some kind of animation will show up in the dope sheet.  A sort of mickey-mousey way to fix this would be to add a temporary keyframe to the object so that it will show up in the dope sheet, paste the new keyframes in from the other object, and delete the temp keyframe.

Comment: Note that the other object won't show up in the dopesheet unless it already has some animation. You might want to add a keyframe to it temporarily, copy the animation, and then remove that temporary key.

Comment: @GregZaal Good point!

Comment: Also, start by setting the current frame to zero to have the animation copied and pasted to the same frames.

Comment: Furthermore, seems like the keyframe transform must be of the same kind, for example, I used "disable in renders" state as the temp keyframe, but then when pasting location transforms, the location was not keyframed (?). So if you are pasting transforms (location, rotation, scale) make sure the temp keyframe also is a transform.