# How to update appended object/armature, while keeping existing animation?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, linked-data, append

I've appended a character object(along with armature) to a project. After animating a bit, I found something I wanted to improve upon in the character armature.

I have the orignal character object in blend #1 and my current project(where I've appended to) we'll call blend #2.

Is it possible to make changes in the armature in blend #1 and reload/update the armature in blend #2, while keeping the existing animation (animation that was in blend #2)?

Comment: try this with armature data : http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24455/can-i-replace-an-object-with-another-object-and-keep-animation/24457#24457

Comment: @Bithur Tried appending a new version of the character object. Then I renamed the old character's armature to "Old" and the newly appened character's armature to "New". But if I change the newest character's armature to "Old", nothing happens(under "Browse armature data to be linked").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select your old armature. In armature settings, change the armature data with the new one.

[image]
[image]