# Animate changing topology of a mesh

Tags: modeling, animation, scripting, geometry

How can I animate a complete change of geometry in Blender? For example, I want a sphere to turn into a cube from one frame to another. This means the object that I am animating is not only changing the shape of the geometry, but also the face/vertices/edge count. I have viewed this question: [Can I replace an object with another object and keep animation?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24455/can-i-replace-an-object-with-another-object-and-keep-animation) After seeing that question, I was wondering if I could keyframe the change in mesh data. Maybe using a script?

The final result would be a stop-motion effect. I would model a different mesh for each frame. So each frame the object would have a mesh that was different from the last, like a fluid simulation which changes the mesh every frame.

Is this possible? A answer using scripts is welcome as well.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/75125/935) help? Having mismatched mesh, I would try a mid shape that each morphs to/from, as in the cube morphs to a sphere, then is hidden and a sphere becomes visible and morphs into a monkey.

Comment: I want to do something similar, but the two shapes have a different number of vertices. It doesn't need to happen slowly either. The change needs to happen over one frame.

Comment: Over one frame, just [animate the render visibility](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8678/935) so that one object disappears and the other appears.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80868/transforming-morphing-one-objects-shape-into-anothers