# Reuse same UV map for duplicate objects

Tags: uv

I have following object:

[image: Windmill]

All 4 hand of windmill are duplicates of each other, only rotated. I already UV mapped 1 hand and now I'd like to use same UV map and textures on other hands. When I try to unwrap other hands, I don't get the same UV map and I can't reuse same texture. The result of trying can be seen on 2nd hand. Is it possible to reuse textures and UV maps?

Comment: if you did not modify the objects in edit mode, you can try this method : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24457/11431

Comment: Make instanced dplicate copies of the object instead, UV data should be kept in sync automatically.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, please post that as answer and possibly add this link: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/duplication.html#linked-duplicates. Thanks, that helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blender supports linked duplicates where new linked object has all data linked to the original object. More info in [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/duplicate_linked.html).

Answer (score 0):

Even if you edited the objects(same vertex count with different mesh data), you can still use ctrl+L to copy UV map.